# Чем обусловлен минимальный предельно допустимый размер объекта?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, стандарт

В стандарте указан рекомендованный минимальный предельно допустимый размер для объекта — [262144](https://eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.17). Чем обусловлено именно это магическое число? Почему не меньше/больше?

Comment: может потому что это 256КБ - размер Кэша 2 уровня во многих процессорах?

Comment: Ни разу не видел таких огромных объектов. Вот объектов от одного байта полно.

Comment: @AlexF в чём именно? Имеется в виду "максимальный размер объекта, который является минимумом, рекомендованным стандартом". Попробуйте перефразировать лучше правкой, если это неясно.

Comment: Вообще, там что-то многие значения кажутся взятыми с потолка...

Comment: Могу лишь обратить внимание, что типичное  минимальное выравнивание для double это 8. Если 256K разделить на 8, то получим 64K, число, которое влезает в 16 бит.

Comment: Это ответ, так как он опровергает утверждение о том, что 262144, якобы, является нижним пределом размера объекта.

Comment: Интересно, что из всех норматив вас заинтересовало только это. Там все числа  соответствуют степени двойки...

Comment: @ТарасАтавин Такого утверждения - `является нижним пределом размера объекта. `  - нигде нет, это ваша интерпретация, видимо, но она неверна.

Comment: Вы серьёзно считаете, что любой объект должен полностью заполнять собой кэш?

Comment: Причём тут кэш? Вы, вероятно, что-то не то думаете про понятие `минимальный предельно допустимый размер объекта`. Компилятор, соответствующий стандарту,  может ограничивать размер объекта, но это ограничение  не должно быть меньшим, чем 256K. Про мелкие объекты тут и речи нет.

Answer (score 1):

Конечным продуктом  кода, является машинный код, что генерируют компиляторы. Вы можете прочитать как работают компиляторы, например [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80#%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

И станет понятно почему для внутренней реализации(создания объектного файла), для каждого объекта нужно больше  памяти для информации о типе и других, которая будет  храниться в этом машинном  коде объекта. Так вот, этот набор бит, насколько стало понятно, **рекомендуется** количеством  в `19` (минимум 19 нулей и единиц). Эта информация в таблице  указана в виде числа(минимальное  значение 19 битовом поле). Это есть

```
(1 << 18)  == 262144
```

на один больше максимального значения 18 битового поля.

Конечно это внутренняя реализация и не касается исходного кода. Сам объект будет хранится в памяти в нужном выравненном виде.

Comment: Так а почему именно 19? Не 10, не 16, а 19.

Comment: А где вы прочли о такой рекомендации? Можно ли предположить, что там описано как вся справочная информация об объекте (тип и т.п.) укладываются в 13 бит? (19 + 13 = 32)

Comment: Сам объект будет чем? Кто хранится?

Comment: #include <iostream>
class A
{

};
int main ()
{
 A a;
 std::cout<<(sizeof(a))<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
выводит 1. И 19 бит не кратны байту.

Comment: @Qwertiy, для ответа на этот вопрос, думаю, наверное нужны специалисты из  кругов разработчиков компиляторов, коим я не являюсь, потому не знаю четкого ответа.

Comment: @ТарасАтавин, что твой код должен показывать?

Comment: Реальный минимальный размер объекта. Это же очевидно.

Comment: @ТарасАтавин, а какое отношение к вопросу имеет минимальный размер объекта? Вопрос о том, почему компиляторы должны поддерживать _максимальный_ размер объекта _не менее чем_ 262144.

Comment: Ну он же спрашивает, чем обусловлен минимальный размер объекта 262144. А на самом деле 1.

Comment: О максимуме там ни слова. Соответственно, не поминается и никакой минимакс. Ни максимум минимума, ни минимум максимума.

Comment: @ТарасАтавин, о максимуме в вопросе говорит фраза _"предельно допустимый размер",_ а в стандарте - _"The limits"_ и _"the minimum for that quantity"._ И если ты не зовёшь через `@`, то уведомление не приходит.

Comment: Нет. Предел может быть и нижним. И там как раз написано: «минимальный предельно допустимый размер», что как раз и говорит о нижнем пределе. И не надо мне рассказывать, как это правильно переводится с английского: вопрос-то написан по-русски.

Comment: Кстати, в физике есть очень интересный минимакс – масса планкеона. Это верхний предел не минимума, а просто массы кванта и одновременно нижний предел не максимума, а просто массы чёрной дыры.